# Will performance improve if I run my app as a service

Tags: c#, service

At present I have c# app.

Its sole purpose is to acquire image from a digital camera and upload it to my server.

I was wondering if performance would be improved it I run it as a service instead?

I know this seems a lucid question and I have searched around on Google but have not got any answers.

Comment: Do you have any other reason except performance to use it as a service?

Comment: @OrkunBekar sorry for the delay in reply. No, no other reason was just curious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, performance will not improve. Services are not faster than other applications. It's the same code run on the same machine.

You should first measure *what* makes your application slow and *then* optimize it.

Comment: Hi, my app is not slow.  I was just curious. You have given me my answer - thanks :)

Comment: HI again, Was going to answer but there are 2 closers and their reasons may be justified. I will see if more closers appear before accepting or deleting question..